# Find customer lapse across variable subscription periods

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hoping someone has run across this issue previously and has a solution. 
I am trying to find customers who lapse based off subscription periods rather than a single order date. 
Lapse is defined by us as not making a purchase/renewal within 30 days of the end of their subscription.  A customer can have multiple subscriptions simultaneously and subscriptions can vary in length.
I have a data set that includes customerIDs, Orders, the subscription start date, the subscription expire date, and that order’s rank in the customer’s order history, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE  #Subscriptions 
(CustomerID INT, 
Orderid INT, 
SubscriptionStart DATE, 
SubscriptionEnd DATE, 
OrderNumber INT);

INSERT INTO #Subscriptions
VALUES(1,   111111, '2017-01-01',   '2017-12-31',   1),
(1, 211111, '2018-01-01',   '2019-12-31'    ,2),
(1, 311121, '2018-10-01', '2018-10-02', 3),
(1, 451515, '2019-02-01',   '2019-02-28',   4),
(2, 158797, '2018-07-01',   '2018-07-31',   1),
(2, 287584, '2018-09-01',   '2018-12-31',   2),
(2, 387452, '2019-01-01',   '2019-01-31',   3),
(3, 187498, '2019-01-01',   '2019-02-28',   1),
(3, 284990, '2019-02-01',   '2019-02-28',   2),
(4, 184849, '2019-02-01',   '2019-02-28',   1)
```

Within this data set, customer 2 would have lapsed on 2018-07-31. Since Customer 1 has a subscription of 2017-01-01 - 2017-12-31 and then one that starts 2018-01-01 and ends 2019-12-31 they cannot lapse within that time period even if other orders made by the customer would qualify.

I have attempt some of simple gap calculations using LEAD() and LAG(), however, I have had no success due to the variable lengths of the subscription period where a single subscription can span across multiple other orders. Eventually, we will use this to calculate monthly churn rate across approximately 5 million records.

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this trying to use LEAD() and LAG().   All you need is a NOT EXISTS() function in the WHERE clause

In psuedocode:

```
SELECT...FROM...
WHERE {SubscriptionEnd is at least 30 days in the past}
AND NOT EXISTS(
  {A row for the same Customer where the StartDate is 30 days or less after this EndDate}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This one looks to be a tricky one.  You are correct about the problem with using the LEAD() and LAG() functions. It stems from customers being able to have multiple subscriptions of variable length.  So we need to deal with that issue first.  Let's begin with creating a single list of dates instead of having a list of SubscriptionStart and SubscriptionEnd.

```
SELECT 
    CustomerId,
    OrderId,
    1 AS Activity,
    SubscriptionStart AS ActivityDate
FROM 
    #Subscriptions

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    CustomerId,
    OrderId,
    -1 AS Activity,
    SubscriptionEnd AS ActivityDate
FROM 
    #Subscriptions
ORDER BY
    CustomerId,
    ActivityDate
```

```
CustomerId  OrderId     Activity    ActivityDate
----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
1           111111      1           2017-01-01
1           111111      -1          2017-12-31
1           211111      1           2018-01-01
1           311121      1           2018-10-01
1           311121      -1          2018-10-02
1           451515      1           2019-02-01
1           451515      -1          2019-02-28
1           211111      -1          2019-12-31
2           158797      1           2018-07-01
2           158797      -1          2018-07-31
2           287584      1           2018-09-01
2           287584      -1          2018-12-31
2           387452      1           2019-01-01
2           387452      -1          2019-01-31
3           187498      1           2019-01-01
3           284990      1           2019-02-01
3           187498      -1          2019-02-28
3           284990      -1          2019-02-28
4           184849      1           2019-02-01
4           184849      -1          2019-02-28
```

Notice the additional Activity field.  It is 1 for the SubscriptionStart and -1 for the SubscriptionEnd.

Using this new Activity field it is possible to find places where there might be a lapse in the customer's subscriptions.  At the same time use LEAD() to find the NextDate.

```
;WITH SubscriptionList AS (
    SELECT 
        CustomerId,
        OrderId,
        1 AS Activity,
        SubscriptionStart AS ActivityDate
    FROM 
        #Subscriptions

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CustomerId,
        OrderId,
        -1 AS Activity,
        SubscriptionEnd AS ActivityDate
    FROM 
        #Subscriptions
)
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    OrderId,
    Activity,
    SUM(Activity) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY ActivityDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as SubscriptionCount,
    ActivityDate,
    LEAD(ActivityDate, 1, GETDATE()) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY ActivityDate) AS NextDate,
    DATEDIFF(d, ActivityDate, LEAD(ActivityDate, 1, GETDATE()) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY ActivityDate)) AS LapsedDays
FROM
    SubscriptionList
ORDER BY
    CustomerId,
    ActivityDate
```

```
CustomerId  OrderId     Activity    SubscriptionCount ActivityDate NextDate   LapsedDays
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------- ------------ ---------- -----------
1           111111      1           1                 2017-01-01   2017-12-31 364
1           111111      -1          0                 2017-12-31   2018-01-01 1
1           211111      1           1                 2018-01-01   2018-10-01 273
1           311121      1           2                 2018-10-01   2018-10-02 1
1           311121      -1          1                 2018-10-02   2019-02-01 122
1           451515      1           2                 2019-02-01   2019-02-28 27
1           451515      -1          1                 2019-02-28   2019-12-31 306
1           211111      -1          0                 2019-12-31   2019-02-28 -306
2           158797      1           1                 2018-07-01   2018-07-31 30
2           158797      -1          0                 2018-07-31   2018-09-01 32
2           287584      1           1                 2018-09-01   2018-12-31 121
2           287584      -1          0                 2018-12-31   2019-01-01 1
2           387452      1           1                 2019-01-01   2019-01-31 30
2           387452      -1          0                 2019-01-31   2019-02-28 28
3           187498      1           1                 2019-01-01   2019-02-01 31
3           284990      1           2                 2019-02-01   2019-02-28 27
3           187498      -1          1                 2019-02-28   2019-02-28 0
3           284990      -1          0                 2019-02-28   2019-02-28 0
4           184849      1           1                 2019-02-01   2019-02-28 27
4           184849      -1          0                 2019-02-28   2019-02-28 0
```

Adding running total on the Activity field will effectively give the number of active subscriptions.  While it is greater than 0 a lapse is not possible.  So focus in on the rows WHERE the SubscriptionCount is zero.

Using LEAD() get the NextDate.  If there isn't a next date then default to today.  If the SubscriptionCount is 0 then the NextDate has to be from a new subscription and the NextDate will be the date that the new subscription starts.  Using DATEDIFF count the number of days between the SubscriptionEnd and the SubscriptionBegin if it is > 30 days then there was a lapse.  Sounds like a good WHERE statement.

```
;WITH SubscriptionList AS (
    SELECT 
        CustomerId,
        OrderId,
        1 AS Activity,
        SubscriptionStart AS ActivityDate
    FROM 
        #Subscriptions

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        CustomerId,
        OrderId,
        -1 AS Activity,
        SubscriptionEnd AS ActivityDate
    FROM 
        #Subscriptions
)
, FindLapse AS (
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    OrderId,
    Activity,
    SUM(Activity) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY ActivityDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as SubscriptionCount,
    ActivityDate,
    LEAD(ActivityDate, 1, GETDATE()) OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY ActivityDate) AS NextDate
FROM
    SubscriptionList
)
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    OrderId,
    Activity,
    SubscriptionCount,
    ActivityDate,
    NextDate,
    DATEDIFF(d, ActivityDate, NextDate) AS LapsedDays
FROM
    FindLapse
WHERE
    SubscriptionCount = 0
    AND DATEDIFF(d, ActivityDate, NextDate) >= 30
```

```
CustomerId  OrderId     Activity    SubscriptionCount ActivityDate NextDate   LapsedDays
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------- ------------ ---------- -----------
2           158797      -1          0                 2018-07-31   2018-09-01 32
```

Looks like we have a winner!